# google app engine configure a specific image / snapshot / docker?

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, google-cloud-platform

here is my worker.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
vm: true
service: worker
env_variables:
  PYTHON_ENV: lab
network:
  instance_tag: testing
  name: my-network

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: worker.app
  login: admin
```

I have some dependencies for it , for example `openCV`, `boost` in a very specific configuration.

I have a machine configured and I have its snapshot and image.

How can I configure the yaml (or anywhere else) to tell app engine to use this image to run the code?

Comment: When you _snapshot_ you mean a GCE machine snapshot?

Comment: @MeLight, yes indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `worker.yaml` uses the default `python27` GAE flexible runtime dockerfile. From the `Dockerfile` row in the [About Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes) comparison table:

> - Flexible runtime: Default file supplied automatically by the SDK
> - Custom runtime: Hand-written by the developer

So you'd need to prepare a custom docker file for it, which could be the GCE one you have or one based on it, as needed. See [Building Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/).